# JS/Pug - " Can't read document.getElementById of undefined"

Tags: javascript, pug

I'm trying to grab an id so I can insert a string into it and it updates every second, I placed the p tag above the function but for some reason, it still doesn't recognize the id.

I inspected the element and the p tag does have an id of timer

I'm pretty new to using Jade so any help would be appreciated

```
   if user && (user._id == wager.opponent || user._id == owner._id) && (wager.playerJoined.getTime() + 1800000 >=  currentTime.getTime())
    p#timer yo
    - function timer(){ setInterval(function() {
    -   var currentTime = new Date();
    -   var timeLeft = Math.floor(((wager.playerJoined.getTime() + 1800000) - currentTime.getTime()) / 60000) + ":" + ("0" + (Math.floor(((wager.playerJoined.getTime() + 1800000) - currentTime.getTime()) % (1000 * 60) / 1000))).substr(-2, 2);
    -   document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = timeLeft;

    -   if (wager.playerJoined.getTime() + 1800000 - currentTime.getTime() < 0) {
    -           clearInterval(interval);            
    -    }

    -}, 1000);
    -};
    - timer();
    button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Submit Results
```

Comment: Do you have element with ID `timer`?

Comment: Yeah, its on the second line

Comment: Could you try to wrap the script execution with `window.addEventListener('load', function() { ...` so that it is executed only after the page is fully loaded?

Comment: I wrapped it around the whole function and I also tried just wrapping it around timer(); They both gave me "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined"

Comment: This would mean the global host object, the `window` is undefined. Are you sure your script runs in a browser?